# Is it okay to use conda-forge as a higher priority channel in Anaconda config settings?

Tags: python, conda-forge

I ran into problems installing xlwings version 0.19.1 and one of our SO contributors helped me by advising to install xlwings using conda-forge. 
I went through more documentation and realised that we can have multiple channels in our .condarc file to enable packages to be searched across channels. One of the docs suggested defining the `channel_priority: strict`. I ran the same after adding conda-forge in my list of channels but, the system started to identify incompatible packages and I chose to terminate the same after close to 4 hours.

I wanted to know  -

1. Is it okay to add conda-forge on top of the default channel ?
2. When I run conda update --all, will the system look for packages in both conda-forge and default channel and prioritize the conda-forge channel version?
3. Will the above actions cause any future problems for me in terms of running conda update --all (as I read questions on package inconsistencies) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) yes, (2) yes, (3) it is supposed to work smoothly, but adding more complexity leads to more potential points of failures. 
Generally I would advice against `channel_priority: strict` I personally experienced solver problems when updating. Does `conda update --all` work for you if you set `channel_priority` back to `flexible`?

Comment: @cel I am currently reinstalling the entire anaconda package. I initially used `conda install --revision 1` and then, tried to uninstall anaconda using  `conda install anaconda-clean`. Unfortunately, I started getting a lot of error messages. Hence, I manually deleted all Anaconda folders in my base environment and deleted the program from Control Panel. I will share an update on the channel priority once I can successfully reinstall the system. Thanks for your response to the first two questions. I will use the inputs while re-installing the fresh setup.